# Object literal (hash) with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a situation where it would be quite convenient to use `Promise.all` like so `Promise.all({})` instead of the more standard Promise.all([]).

but this doesn't seem to work

```
Promise.all({a:1,b:2}).then(function(val){
   console.log('val:',val);
});
```

whilst this does of course

```
Promise.all([1,2,3]).then(function(val){
   console.log('val:',val);
});
```

(what I would expect would be for Promise.all to map the values of the Object literal, but leave the keys intact.)

But [the MDN docs for Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) seem to indicate that Promise all will work for any iterable. To my knowledge, an object literal `{}` is an iterable. So what am I missing?

Comment: No, `{}` is not an iterable.

Comment: It's not clear from these docs whether {} is an iterable or not, but it appears it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: @AlexMills Not sure why you think it's not clear. The MDN article you linked explains "*some built-in types are built-in iterables with a default iteration behavior, such as Array or Map, while other types (such as Object) are not*".

Comment: If you are wondering whether `{}` is an iterable or not, try typing any of the following into the console. (1) `[...{}]` (2) `for (i of {}) {}`.

Comment: Why would it really be convenient anyway?  You're not explaining what you're trying to do. There are a lot of possible things you could be trying to do, but none of them really make sense for just cramming an object into Promise.all, whose purpose is to merge Promises, which doesn't look like what your'e trying to do.

Comment: what I am trying to do is very similar to how I would use async.parallel with an object instead of an array, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object does not have an Iterator symbol if you look at the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for those.

What you can do, is use a tool function to create an object iterable and later consume it.

[reference to objectEntries source](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-iteration.html), however nodejs does not implement Reflect, so for the purpose of using it with node I just change it into using Object.keys()

```
function objectEntries(obj) {
    let index = 0;

    // In ES6, you can use strings or symbols as property keys,
    // Reflect.ownKeys() retrieves both
    let propKeys = Object.keys(obj);

    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            if (index < propKeys.length) {
                let key = propKeys[index];
                index++;
                return { value: [key, obj[key]] };
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another async / await ES6 solution:

```
async function allOf(hash = {}) {
  const promises = Object.keys(hash).map(async key => ({[key]: await hash[key]}));
  const resolved = await Promise.all(promises);
  return resolved.reduce((hash, part) => ({...hash, ...part}), {});
}
```

This converts the keys into a promise that produces a single element hash. Then at the end we combine all the hashes in the array to a single hash. You could compact this to a one-liner even, at the cost of readability.

```
async function allOfOneLiner(hash = {}) {
  return (await Promise.all(Object.keys(hash).map(async k => ({[k]: await hash[k]})))).reduce((h, p) => ({...h, ...p}), {});
}
```

Comment: This is really elegant, very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Works in Firefox Nightly:

```js
Promise.all(Object.values({a:1,b:2}))
.then(vals => console.log('vals: ' + vals)) // vals: 1,2
.catch(e => console.log(e));

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Then, to put the results back in an object, we can make a `Promise.allParams` function:

```js
Promise.allParams = o => 
  Promise.all(Object.values(o)).then(promises =>
    Object.keys(o).reduce((o2, key, i) => (o2[key] = promises[i], o2), {}));

// Demo:

Promise.allParams({a:1,b:2}).then(function(val){
   console.log('val: ' + JSON.stringify(val)); // val: {"a":1,"b":2}
});

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: This solution suffers from the problem that the order of the elements in the resulting array depends on the order of the values in the array returned by `Object.values`, which is probably not something you want to depend on.

Comment: @torazaburo of course, but that problem is inherent in the question.

Comment: It's not. You should return a hash of promise results, as RSVP does.

Comment: @torazaburo ah, missed that. Updated.

Comment: Note `Object.values` is only a proposal, but it isn't in the official ECMAScript draft yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
Syntax
Promise.all(iterable);
Parameters
```

> iterable
>
> An iterable object, such as an Array. See iterable.

Comment: I am not sure about that, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Answer (score 1):

This function does the trick:

```
Promise.allAssoc = function(object){
    var values = [], keys = [];
    for(var key in object){
        values.push(object[key]);
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return Promise.all(values).then(function(results){
        var out = {};
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) out[keys[i]] = results[i];
        return out;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all objects are iterable by default. You can make an object iterable by defining a `@@iterator` method. `@@iterator` is a [Well-Known Symbol](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-well-known-symbols) available as `Symbol.iterator`:

> - Specification Name
>     @@iterator
> - [[Description]]
>     "Symbol.iterator"
> - Value and Purpose
>     A method that returns the default Iterator for an object. Called by the semantics of the for-of statement.

For example, this will make all object iterable (probably not a good idea):

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  for(let key of Object.keys(this))
    yield this[key];
};
```

Then you will be able to use

```
Promise.all({a:1,b:2}).then(function(val){
   console.log('val:', val); // [ 1, 2 ]
});
```

Comment: is there a way to modify this easily so that 'then' callback passes us an object/hash with the original keys matching with the values instead of an array?

Comment: @AlexMills I don't understand. You want to call `Promise.all` with an object, and get that same object? What's the point?

Comment: :) I want to use Promise.all and map the values from the Promise to the Promise result while leaving the key intact. So {a: Promise} becomes {a:'some-other-value'}

Comment: @AlexMills That makes sense, but I don't think you can. I don't know much about Promises, though.

Comment: Yeah I tried and I dont think it's possiblr without changing the internal implementation of Promise.all

Comment: It's possible check my answer

Answer (score 0):

With Babel/ES2015 you can use Object.keys and map to get the values like this:

```
const obj = {a:1,b:2};                                                                                                                               
const vals = Object.keys(obj).map(k=>obj[k]);                                                                                                        
Promise.all(vals).then( vals => { console.log('vals', vals) });
```

Comment: I suspect the OP would prefer to return a hash with promises as the values of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 way

```
Promise.hashProperties = async function(object) {
    const keys = [];
    const values = [];

    for (const key in object) {
        keys.push(key);
        values.push(object[key]);
    }

    const results = await Promise.all(values);

    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
        object[keys[i]] = results[i];

    return object;
};
```